# Generic version of this function

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

In my quest of reviewing my old code i came across this:

```
private void InitializeRow(GridViewRowInfo destRow, GridViewRowInfo sourceRow) 
{
    destRow.Cells["Image"].Value = sourceRow.Cells["Image"].Value; 
    destRow.Cells["Name"].Value = sourceRow.Cells["Name"].Value; 
    destRow.Cells["Country"].Value = sourceRow.Cells["Country"].Value; 
    destRow.Cells["Price"].Value = sourceRow.Cells["Price"].Value; 
}
```

I want to rewrite it in something more generic, to not have to write every columns name as string. Assuming that they are the same but not in the same order so I can't use index. Into something like this :

```
private void InitializeRow(GridViewRowInfo destRow, GridViewRowInfo sourceRow) 
{
    foreach (GridViewCellInfoCollection Csource in sourceRow.Cells)
    { 
        destRow.Cells.OfType<Csource.GetType()> =
            sourceRow.Cells.OfType<Csource.GetType()> ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: This is maybe more suited for Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you can get the name, just use it in the loop: Cells[name], otherwise you can loop over an array of your cells to avoid the extra typing

Comment: The question is how do i do that. getting the name in a variable like Aw04 said. peolpe ask here how they can decalre a variable , so my question is not valid because i have no problem except procrastination ?

Comment: This is for telerik grid, right?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Yes it's for telerik. Nice one btw i always get lost in the properties. I m adding the telerik tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is for Telerik grid, you can probably do something like this:

```
private void InitializeRow(GridViewRowInfo destRow, GridViewRowInfo sourceRow) 
{
    foreach (GridViewCellInfo Csource in sourceRow.Cells)
    { 
        destRow.Cells[Csource.ColumnInfo.Name].Value = Csource.Value;
    }
}
```